# Update chart with new data not working

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm drawing a bar chart with some initial data and then trying to update when a button is clicked. I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined". The error occurs after update buttom is clicked. How do I fix this and enable the update function to draw a new bar chart?

```
<div id="chart"></div>
<button id="update" onclick="update()">Update</button>
```

D3 code:

```
    var myData = [21, 3, 5, 21, 15];
    //Width and height
    var w = 250;
    var h = 250;
    var yScale = null;

    function draw(initialData) {
      var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .domain(d3.range(initialData.length))
        .rangeRoundBands([0, w], 0.05);

      yScale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(initialData)])
        .range([0, h]);

      //Create SVG element
      var svg = d3.select("#chart")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h);

      svg.selectAll("rect")
        .data(initialData)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("x", function(d, i) {
          return xScale(i);
        })
        .attr("y", function(d) {
          return h - yScale(d);
        })
        .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand())
        .attr("height", function(d) {
          return yScale(d);
        })
        .attr("fill", "steelblue");

      svg.selectAll("text")
        .data(initialData)
        .enter()
        .append("text")
        .text(function(d) {
          return d;
        })
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("x", function(d, i) {
          return xScale(i) + xScale.rangeBand() / 2;
        })
        .attr("y", function(d) {
          return h - yScale(d) + 14;
        })
        .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
        .attr("font-size", "11px")
        .attr("fill", "white");
    }

    draw(myData);

    var newData = [15, 5, 3, 15, 21];
    //update function
    function update(newData) {
      yScale.domain([0, d3.max(newData)]);

      var rects = d3.select("#chart svg")
        .selectAll("rect")
        .data(newData);

      // enter selection
      rects
        .enter().append("rect");

      // update selection
      rects
        .transition()
        .duration(300)
        .attr("y", function(d) {
          return h - yScale(d);
        })
        .attr("height", function(d) {
          return yScale(d);
        })

      // exit selection
      rects
        .exit().remove();

      var texts = d3.select("#chart svg")
        .selectAll("text")
        .data(newData);

      // enter selection
      texts
        .enter().append("rect");

      // update selection
      texts
        .transition()
        .duration(300)
        .attr("y", function(d) {
          return h - yScale(d) + 14;
        })
        .text(function(d) {
          return d;
        })

      // exit selection
      texts
        .exit().remove();
    }
```

Comment: Editing the solution into the question completely defaces the answer by eradicating the problem! I just rolled back the edit to show the initial problem. You have already marked the answer as helpful, which is the right way of indicating the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your update function expects an array of data as parameter but you call it without params.
You can add button click listener using d3 like that.

```
d3.select("#update").on("click", function(){ update(newData); })
```

Created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2e99Lc38/) for you

Comment: Thank you Daniela! I updated the js above to reflect the change that makes it work.